# Android/Cyanogen 7 RC4/ADW Icon Size?

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

Im trying to make custom icons for my HTC EVO, which is running Cyanogen 7 RC4, uses ADW Launcher and such.

If you make a custom power management toolbar, it fills the entire length of the screen. Im wondering what the dimensions of that bar are? i think its 4 icons + the space in between by 1 icon high.

I also remember seeing somewhere an app that lets you measure things on your screen in pixels.... does anyone know what the app is called or can link me directly to it?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I ended up unpacking the framework-res.apk file and taking a look at the various icons inside the apks in there. I believe for HDPI devices, the standard icon size is 90 by 90 pixels.